# Better way to pass streaming data using service WCF or TCP or Web API

Tags: web-services, wcf, tcp, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a service which will pass data as stream from server to clients.

I want to know what is the better and fastest way to do this

using WCF

using TCP

or using Web API

EDIT: I am creating a windows application where several clients will be served by a centralized server. This service will pass data as stream from server to clients.

Comment: You've left out some details. Is this streaming happening over at network between two servers, or from a phone to a website? The answer depends on the context of the transmission.

Comment: Adding to Brian's questions - is this for `localhost`; `intranet` or for over the `Internet`?  This will further impact choice of _API_ and/or _transport_